# Visual studio C++ relative path

Tags: c++-cli, relative-path

In Visual studio C++/Cli, relative pathes are relative to what? Which directory is equivalent to "." ? For example, if the solution file is at "C:\dir1\project.sln" the where is "."?

Comment: Are you talking about the project property pages or in the code? The relative path should be based off of the project's output directory, not where the solution is.

Comment: I mean in the code.

Comment: Now it looks a little weird, that when I run the output program from win explorer, it searches for the files in the output directory (C:\dir1\debug = .), but running that program from the visual studio, C:\dir1\dir1 = ., which is strange, because they are the same .exe files!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At runtime, relative paths are relative to the [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) that the application was started with.

- When you run from Visual Studio, the working directory is where the project file is located.
- When you double-click an exe in Windows Explorer, the working directory is generally the same as where the exe is located.
- From the command line, you can have the working directory be anything: navigate to the directory you want to use as the working directory, and run your exe by typing the full path.